# dijit ValidationTextBox how to add minlength and maxlength

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form

I would like to know how (with simple working example) to add `maxlength` and `minlength` to input tag generated by

```
dijit/form/ValidationTextBox
```

Example of desired output:

```
<input maxlength="10" minlength="2" class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" autocomplete="off" name="title" type="text" tabindex="0" id="Image-1-title-LabelValidationTextBox" aria-required="undefined" value="Title text for image Image-1" aria-invalid="false">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this example with regex constraint

```
<input type="text" value="someTestString" required="true"
data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox"
data-dojo-props="regExp: '[a-zA-Z0-9$%!_]{2,10}', invalidMessage: 'The value must be at least 2 character and maximum 10'" />
```

Comment: Thanks you this solved my problem, without using constraint

Answer (score 2):

ValidationTextBox has the properties minLength and maxLength. They are used in the following why in a declarative manner.

```
  <input  data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox"
            data-dojo-props="required:true,
                            maxLength:5,
                            minLength:2"
                            type="text" 
                            name="exmaple" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's another solution:

```
registry.byId("validationTextBox").validator = function(value, constraints) {
    if(value) {
        return value.length >= 2 && value.length <= 10;
    }
    return true;
}
```